# wordpress renewal failed, showing blank pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I was working on renewal of this site http://koogen.net/, I created a sub-directory under the name of /wp/ and installed wordpress, worked on renewed version of the website.

I finally got green light and was working on changing the settings for wordpress so that users can view the renewed website just by accessing koogen.net.

I changed

- site address to http://koogen.net/
- copied index.php and .htaccess to the root directory.
- Edited index.php's

  require(‘/wp-blog-header.php’); to
  require(‘/wp/wp-blog-header.php’);

and

*Edited .htaccess's

```
RewriteBase /wp/
```

to

```
RewriteBase /
```

and

```
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

and I thought that should work fine. But instead they gave me blank pages everywhere and I can't fix them.

**I already tried WP_DEBUG true setting but it's not showing me any error messages**

I am guessing that I messed up my htaccess or my php database.
How could I fix this problem... any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!!

---

UPDATE:
I was able to turn on the DEBUG mode, and it gave me this error message.

> Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /home/dartpacs/koogen.net/public_html/wp/wp-includes/locale.php on line 21

so I looked at it, but I could not find anything wrong with the code... Is there anything that I am missing?

```html
<?php
/**
 * Date and Time Locale object
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage i18n
 */

/**
 * Class that loads the calendar locale.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
class WP_Locale {
 /**
  * Stores the translated strings for the full weekday names.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @var array
  */
 public $weekday;

 /**
  * Stores the translated strings for the one character weekday names.
  *
  * There is a hack to make sure that Tuesday and Thursday, as well
  * as Sunday and Saturday, don't conflict. See init() method for more.
  *
  * @see WP_Locale::init() for how to handle the hack.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @var array
  */
 public $weekday_initial;

 /**
  * Stores the translated strings for the abbreviated weekday names.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @var array
  */
 public $weekday_abbrev;

 /**
  * Stores the translated strings for the full month names.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @var array
  */
 public $month;

 /**
  * Stores the translated strings for the abbreviated month names.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @var array
  */
 public $month_abbrev;

 /**
  * Stores the translated strings for 'am' and 'pm'.
  *
  * Also the capitalized versions.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @var array
  */
 public $meridiem;

 /**
  * The text direction of the locale language.
  *
  * Default is left to right 'ltr'.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @var string
  */
 public $text_direction = 'ltr';

 /**
  * @var array
  */
 public $number_format;

 /**
  * Sets up the translated strings and object properties.
  *
  * The method creates the translatable strings for various
  * calendar elements. Which allows for specifying locale
  * specific calendar names and text direction.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @access private
  */
 function init() {
  // The Weekdays
  $this->weekday[0] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Sunday');
  $this->weekday[1] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Monday');
  $this->weekday[2] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Tuesday');
  $this->weekday[3] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Wednesday');
  $this->weekday[4] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Thursday');
  $this->weekday[5] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Friday');
  $this->weekday[6] = /* translators: weekday */ __('Saturday');

  // The first letter of each day. The _%day%_initial suffix is a hack to make
  // sure the day initials are unique.
  $this->weekday_initial[__('Sunday')]    = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('S_Sunday_initial');
  $this->weekday_initial[__('Monday')]    = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('M_Monday_initial');
  $this->weekday_initial[__('Tuesday')]   = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('T_Tuesday_initial');
  $this->weekday_initial[__('Wednesday')] = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('W_Wednesday_initial');
  $this->weekday_initial[__('Thursday')]  = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('T_Thursday_initial');
  $this->weekday_initial[__('Friday')]    = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('F_Friday_initial');
  $this->weekday_initial[__('Saturday')]  = /* translators: one-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('S_Saturday_initial');

  foreach ($this->weekday_initial as $weekday_ => $weekday_initial_) {
   $this->weekday_initial[$weekday_] = preg_replace('/_.+_initial$/', '', $weekday_initial_);
  }

  // Abbreviations for each day.
  $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Sunday')]    = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Sun');
  $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Monday')]    = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Mon');
  $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Tuesday')]   = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Tue');
  $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Wednesday')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Wed');
  $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Thursday')]  = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Thu');
  $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Friday')]    = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Fri');
  $this->weekday_abbrev[__('Saturday')]  = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the weekday */ __('Sat');

  // The Months
  $this->month['01'] = /* translators: month name */ __('January');
  $this->month['02'] = /* translators: month name */ __('February');
  $this->month['03'] = /* translators: month name */ __('March');
  $this->month['04'] = /* translators: month name */ __('April');
  $this->month['05'] = /* translators: month name */ __('May');
  $this->month['06'] = /* translators: month name */ __('June');
  $this->month['07'] = /* translators: month name */ __('July');
  $this->month['08'] = /* translators: month name */ __('August');
  $this->month['09'] = /* translators: month name */ __('September');
  $this->month['10'] = /* translators: month name */ __('October');
  $this->month['11'] = /* translators: month name */ __('November');
  $this->month['12'] = /* translators: month name */ __('December');

  // Abbreviations for each month. Uses the same hack as above to get around the
  // 'May' duplication.
  $this->month_abbrev[__('January')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Jan_January_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('February')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Feb_February_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('March')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Mar_March_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('April')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Apr_April_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('May')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('May_May_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('June')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Jun_June_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('July')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Jul_July_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('August')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Aug_August_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('September')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Sep_September_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('October')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Oct_October_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('November')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Nov_November_abbreviation');
  $this->month_abbrev[__('December')] = /* translators: three-letter abbreviation of the month */ __('Dec_December_abbreviation');

  foreach ($this->month_abbrev as $month_ => $month_abbrev_) {
   $this->month_abbrev[$month_] = preg_replace('/_.+_abbreviation$/', '', $month_abbrev_);
  }

  // The Meridiems
  $this->meridiem['am'] = __('am');
  $this->meridiem['pm'] = __('pm');
  $this->meridiem['AM'] = __('AM');
  $this->meridiem['PM'] = __('PM');

  // Numbers formatting
  // See http://php.net/number_format

  /* translators: $thousands_sep argument for http://php.net/number_format, default is , */
  $trans = __('number_format_thousands_sep');
  $this->number_format['thousands_sep'] = ('number_format_thousands_sep' == $trans) ? ',' : $trans;

  /* translators: $dec_point argument for http://php.net/number_format, default is . */
  $trans = __('number_format_decimal_point');
  $this->number_format['decimal_point'] = ('number_format_decimal_point' == $trans) ? '.' : $trans;

  // Set text direction.
  if ( isset( $GLOBALS['text_direction'] ) )
   $this->text_direction = $GLOBALS['text_direction'];
  /* translators: 'rtl' or 'ltr'. This sets the text direction for WordPress. */
  elseif ( 'rtl' == _x( 'ltr', 'text direction' ) )
   $this->text_direction = 'rtl';

  if ( 'rtl' === $this->text_direction && strpos( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '-src' ) ) {
   $this->text_direction = 'ltr';
   add_action( 'all_admin_notices', array( $this, 'rtl_src_admin_notice' ) );
  }
 }

 function rtl_src_admin_notice() {
  echo '<div class="error"><p>' . 'The <code>build</code> directory of the develop repository must be used for RTL.' . '</p></div>';
 }

 /**
  * Retrieve the full translated weekday word.
  *
  * Week starts on translated Sunday and can be fetched
  * by using 0 (zero). So the week starts with 0 (zero)
  * and ends on Saturday with is fetched by using 6 (six).
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @param int $weekday_number 0 for Sunday through 6 Saturday
  * @return string Full translated weekday
  */
 function get_weekday($weekday_number) {
  return $this->weekday[$weekday_number];
 }

 /**
  * Retrieve the translated weekday initial.
  *
  * The weekday initial is retrieved by the translated
  * full weekday word. When translating the weekday initial
  * pay attention to make sure that the starting letter does
  * not conflict.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @param string $weekday_name
  * @return string
  */
 function get_weekday_initial($weekday_name) {
  return $this->weekday_initial[$weekday_name];
 }

 /**
  * Retrieve the translated weekday abbreviation.
  *
  * The weekday abbreviation is retrieved by the translated
  * full weekday word.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @param string $weekday_name Full translated weekday word
  * @return string Translated weekday abbreviation
  */
 function get_weekday_abbrev($weekday_name) {
  return $this->weekday_abbrev[$weekday_name];
 }

 /**
  * Retrieve the full translated month by month number.
  *
  * The $month_number parameter has to be a string
  * because it must have the '0' in front of any number
  * that is less than 10. Starts from '01' and ends at
  * '12'.
  *
  * You can use an integer instead and it will add the
  * '0' before the numbers less than 10 for you.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @param string|int $month_number '01' through '12'
  * @return string Translated full month name
  */
 function get_month($month_number) {
  return $this->month[zeroise($month_number, 2)];
 }

 /**
  * Retrieve translated version of month abbreviation string.
  *
  * The $month_name parameter is expected to be the translated or
  * translatable version of the month.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @param string $month_name Translated month to get abbreviated version
  * @return string Translated abbreviated month
  */
 function get_month_abbrev($month_name) {
  return $this->month_abbrev[$month_name];
 }

 /**
  * Retrieve translated version of meridiem string.
  *
  * The $meridiem parameter is expected to not be translated.
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @param string $meridiem Either 'am', 'pm', 'AM', or 'PM'. Not translated version.
  * @return string Translated version
  */
 function get_meridiem($meridiem) {
  return $this->meridiem[$meridiem];
 }

 /**
  * Global variables are deprecated. For backwards compatibility only.
  *
  * @deprecated For backwards compatibility only.
  * @access private
  *
  * @since 2.1.0
  */
 function register_globals() {
  $GLOBALS['weekday']         = $this->weekday;
  $GLOBALS['weekday_initial'] = $this->weekday_initial;
  $GLOBALS['weekday_abbrev']  = $this->weekday_abbrev;
  $GLOBALS['month']           = $this->month;
  $GLOBALS['month_abbrev']    = $this->month_abbrev;
 }

 /**
  * Constructor which calls helper methods to set up object variables
  *
  * @uses WP_Locale::init()
  * @uses WP_Locale::register_globals()
  * @since 2.1.0
  *
  */
 function __construct() {
  $this->init();
  $this->register_globals();
 }

 /**
  * Checks if current locale is RTL.
  *
  * @since 3.0.0
  * @return bool Whether locale is RTL.
  */
 function is_rtl() {
  return 'rtl' == $this->text_direction;
 }

 /**
  * Register date/time format strings for general POT.
  *
  * Private, unused method to add some date/time formats translated
  * on wp-admin/options-general.php to the general POT that would
  * otherwise be added to the admin POT.
  *
  * @since 3.6.0
  */
 function _strings_for_pot() {
  /* translators: localized date format, see http://php.net/date */
  __( 'F j, Y' );
  /* translators: localized time format, see http://php.net/date */
  __( 'g:i a' );
  /* translators: localized date and time format, see http://php.net/date */
  __( 'F j, Y g:i a' );
 }
}

/**
 * Checks if current locale is RTL.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @return bool Whether locale is RTL.
 */
function is_rtl() {
 global $wp_locale;
 return $wp_locale->is_rtl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one myself... I found out that my server was using php4.3 for servers default setting... That is why it was showing parse error... I changed it to the latest version and now it works fine.